# USB topography viewing tool for Windows

Tags: windows, usb

Is there a tool that displays the topography of USB devices on Windows?

Comment: View devices by connection in Device Manager?

Comment: Billc.cn: I was hoping for something like usbview (a Linux tool) for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use **[USB View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560019.aspx)** that ships with the **Windows SDK**. To obtain it, make sure to check the **Debugging Tools** option during the installation of Windows SDK. After installation, `usbview.exe` can be found in the `C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\` directory.